# Rails+Searchkick search on empty params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchkick

I am trying to create a document management system where the user can search for documents by subject or by date. It works fine when both parameters have values or both are empty. But when one is empty, things start to go awry.

I use `params[:search]` to search through the subject field while `params[:date_filter]` is used for the date fields.

Case 1: `params[:search]` is empty, `params[:date_filter]` is present. Search returns nothing.

Case 2: `params[:search]` is present, `params[:date_filter]` is empty. Search results in `ArgumentError invalid date`

While I think I can fix these problems by putting them inside nested `if` clauses, I would like to ask for help if there is a more elegant solution especially if I consider that more parameters would mean more `if` clauses.

Here is the code I'm using in my controller:

```
if params[:search].present? || params[:date_filter].present?

  @ingoing = Document.search(
    params[:search], 
    where: {
      outgoing: false,
      date: {
        gte: DateTime.strptime(params[:date_filter], '%m/%d/%Y %l:%M %p').beginning_of_day, 
        lte: DateTime.strptime(params[:date_filter], '%m/%d/%Y %l:%M %p').end_of_day
      } 
    }, 
    order: {created_at: :desc} )
  @outgoing = Document.search(
    params[:search], 
    where: {
      outgoing: true,
      date: {
        gte: DateTime.strptime(params[:date_filter], '%m/%d/%Y %l:%M %p').beginning_of_day, 
        lte: DateTime.strptime(params[:date_filter], '%m/%d/%Y %l:%M %p').end_of_day
      } 
    }, 
    order: {created_at: :desc} )
else
  @documents = Document.all
  @ingoing = @documents.where(outgoing: false).order('created_at desc')
  @outgoing = @documents.where(outgoing: true).order('created_at desc')
end
```

Update:
Used a modified version of @CupawnTae's code to solve the problem

```
search = params[:search].present? ? params[:search] : "*"
#where = {order: {created_at: :desc}} 
#This kept throwing an unknown where operand error so I changed it
#Also can't put misspellings: false here since it keeps returning empty results
where = {}

if params[:date_filter].present?
  where[:date] = {
    gte: DateTime.strptime(params[:date_filter], '%m/%d/%Y %l:%M %p').beginning_of_day,
    lte: DateTime.strptime(params[:date_filter], '%m/%d/%Y %l:%M %p').end_of_day
  }
end

#Put the order here,  as well as the misspelling option since putting it at the top returned empty results.
@ingoing = Document.search( search, where: where.merge(:outgoing => false), order: {created_at: :desc}, misspellings: false )
@outgoing = Document.search( search, where: where.merge(:outgoing => true), order: {created_at: :desc}, misspellings: false )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
search = params[:search].present? ? params[:search] : "*"
where = {order: {created_at: :desc}}

if params[:date_filter].present?
  where[:date] = {
    gte: DateTime.strptime(params[:date_filter], '%m/%d/%Y %l:%M %p').beginning_of_day,
    lte: DateTime.strptime(params[:date_filter], '%m/%d/%Y %l:%M %p').end_of_day
  }
end

@ingoing = Document.search search, where: where.merge(:outgoing => false)
@outgoing = Document.search search, where: where.merge(:outgoing => true)
```

Comment: Thanks, but now it's ignoring my date inputs and for some reason the `@ingoing` and `@outgoing` variables output the same thing.

Comment: oops, sorry, don't have searchkick here to test - I missed `where:` in the search parameters - try updated code

Comment: Thank you very much! I had to modify some bits because they were throwing up errors or producing blank results but it worked in the end.